# iphone programming getting data from remote server

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

HI,

I'm new to iphone programming and developing travel application, which retrieve most of it data from remote database.

What is the best way to implement this solution? I thought of generating XML files in server side and getting data via XML files to iPhone app and displaying them...

Is there better implementation to this, thank you in advance?

Waruna.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you and the kind of data you are using and any licenseing concerns.

I chose to use json, as data being transferred is more compact, and there is a [json framework available here](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/). There are quite a lot of [tutorials available](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html) for it too.

I've used it very succesfully with a php backend on a couple of projects.

Comment: i also want keep downloaded data on the iphone, to enable users to use application when there is no network connection. Do you think this is the best way to achieve that

Comment: You could easily save the data and use it offline if required.